# IE 11 : Select dropdown with finger Touch is not the same with Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, internet-explorer

I have an **select input** witch shows some options in its drop down:

```
<select name="vendorSelect"  class="col-xs-12 " id="vendorSelect" [(ngModel)]="currentVendor">
    <option  [hidden]="true" disabled [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue" ></option> 
    <option *ngFor="let vendor of listVendor" [ngValue]="vendor">
        {{vendor.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

When running , it goes well in chrome , firefox , safari.

**The difference appears with IE11 and within Tablet:**

- When using the **mouse click** : the dropdown appears normally and with its own scroll bar
- When using **finger (Touch)** : the dropdown appearence got different (with a mobile inspired scrolling with swiping and no scrollbar).

**I want to unify this behavior** , so when *Touching with finger* , i want to display my normal Select-dropdown and not the special one.

The problem is specifically with **IE and EDGE**

Any **suggestions or ideas** about the problem origin ??

Comment: Edge curently (v94) works the same way with tap and click. Unlike IE11 which has the problem you describe even in 20H2

Comment: In IE11, If the dropdown is required to scroll, there is a sort of scroll indicator in the mobile inspired version, however it is thin, has a tendency to disappear & is not itself draggable. It just indicates the relative data size to the visible area & gives a hint as to where you are in the list.